# Add wait spinner for @Url.Action (download file)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Using jQueryMobile I am downloading a file using @Url.Action and a FileStreamResult in the controller class.

Controller Method

```
public ActionResult DownloadPDF()
{
    var stream = myHandler.getFileStream("myfile.pdf");
    return File(stream, "application/pdf", "myfile.pdf"));
}
```

Html code

```
<a href='@Url.Action("DownloadPDF", "Home">
    <div>
        <!-- HTML Content -->
    </div>
</a>
```

Works great! 
But how may I know when the download is complete, to add a wait-spinner?

I want to use the FileStreamResult as the file is not stored on the webserver (stored in db).

Is it possible to "know" when the file is downloaded by using Url.Action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do this, as the page does not know anything about the request (which technically is another page entirely).

You can register that a user clicked on the link, but it is not possible to find any more information about the download request - whether it completed, cancelled or errored.

Comment: I guess my option would be to do a ajax call instead of @Url.Action. Thnx